# How to use wp_dropdown_pages or wp_list_pages to accomplish a menu like this?

Tags: pages, dropdown, child-pages

I spend 2 days on it, trying to use those WP function: wp_dropdown_pages and wp_list_pages, adding some JavaScript but not find out how to make a menu like below.

[image: I would appreciate any help ! Thanks Guys!]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an easy way to generate a dropdown menu from your blog pages using the WordPress wp_dropdown_pages() function.

Adding a bit of javascript you can send the user to the page when they select it

```
  <section id="pageselect">
                <span>
                <?php wp_dropdown_pages('show_option_none=Explore...'); ?>
                </span>
                <script type="text/javascript"><!--
                    var selectmenu = document.getElementById("page_id");
                    function onPageChange() {
                        if ( selectmenu.options[selectmenu.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
                            location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/?page_id="+selectmenu.options[selectmenu.selectedIndex].value;
                        }
                    }
                    selectmenu.onchange = onPageChange;
                --></script>
    </section><!-- end pageselect -->
```

Comment: Thanks but I already try this response find on internet, but if you test it, it doesn't work as it should. You switching from page to page, but "Explore.." is always as default on the menu, and I want to have the Page name on the top of the menu.